# Stochastic Process Notation

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation

Note: I'm not an expert on stochastic processes.  Please use small words and speak real slow.

I'm reading a paper [[1](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aoas/1267453933)], which uses a notation for stochastic processes that doesn't seem to be standard.

> Now we generalize the squared covariance and define the square of
> conditional covariance, given two real-valued stochastic processes
> $U(·)$ and $V(·)$. We obtain an interesting result when $U$ and $V$ are
> independent Weiner processes. First, to center the random variable $X$
> in the conditional covariance, we need the following definition. Let $X$
> be a real-valued random variable and ${U (t):t ∈ ℝ}$ a real-valued
> stochastic process, independent of $X$. The $U$-centered version of $X$
> is defined by
>
> $$X_U = U (X) − \int^∞_{-∞} U (t) dFX(t) = U (X) − E[U (X)|U]$$

In my experience a stochastic process is a collection of random variables $\{X_t\}$... What is the intuition behind a stochastic process $U(·)$?  Also, they have both $U(X)$ and $U(t)$ which I can't make heads or tails of.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U(X)$ just means the stochastic process at a **random time** $X$. So you have two different random things, the stochastic process (collection of random variables) $\{U(t)\}$, and the random time $X$ picks out a particular one $U(X)$.

For instance, imagine you pick a random book from the shelf and open it on a random page. Then $\{U(t)\}$ is the book, $X$ is the page number, and $U(X)$ is the text on that page.

Comment: So $X_U$ is the text on the page, normalized against the average text from all books on that same page.  Thanks for the example.  :)